# Is there something wrong with this opengl es 2.o code for android?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I'm following a tutorial to learn opengl es 2.0 for android from the book OpenGL ES 2 for Android a Quick-Start Guide. I'm on section 3.5 and my "compiled" code won't compile. I've checked and double checked but my code matches from the book. I searched SO and other sites but it seems like it's just me having a problem with this code. I've tried it on an AVD and a jellybean physical device but I always get `Compilation of shader failed` Here is the code I'm trying to compile.

Vertex Code:

```
 attribute vec4 a_Position;
 void main(){
 gl_Position = a_Position;
 }
```

Fragment Code:

```
precision mediump float;
uniform vec4 u_Color;
void main(){
gl_FragColor = u_Color;
}
```

The helper class which locates the resources and compiles the code for opengl:

```
public class ShaderHelper {

private static final String TAG = "ShaderHelper";

public static int compileVertexShader(String shaderCode){
    return compileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, shaderCode);
}

public static int compileFragmentShader(String shaderCode){
    return compileShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, shaderCode);
}

public static int compileShader(int type, String shaderCode){
    final int shaderObjectId = glCreateShader(type);
    if(shaderObjectId == 0){
        if(LoggerConfig.ON){
            Log.w(TAG, "Could not create new shader.");

        }
    }

    final int[] compileStatus = new int[1];
    glGetShaderiv(shaderObjectId, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus, 0);

    if(LoggerConfig.ON){
        Log.v(TAG, "Results of compiling source:" + "\n" + shaderCode + "\n:" + glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderObjectId));
    }

    if(compileStatus[0] == 0){
        glDeleteShader(shaderObjectId);
        if(LoggerConfig.ON){
            Log.w(TAG, "Compilation of shader failed."); <--This is where I get notification that the code did not compile...
        }
        return 0;
    }
    return shaderObjectId;
}

public static int linkProgram(int vertexShaderId, int fragmentShaderId){
    final int programObjectId = glCreateProgram();
    if(programObjectId == 0){
        if (LoggerConfig.ON){
            Log.w(TAG, "Could not create new program.");
        }
        return 0;
    }
    glAttachShader(programObjectId, vertexShaderId);
    glAttachShader(programObjectId, fragmentShaderId);

    final int[] linkStatus = new int[1];
    glGetProgramiv(programObjectId, GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0);

    if(LoggerConfig.ON){
        Log.v(TAG, "Results of linking program:\n" + glGetProgramInfoLog(programObjectId));
    }

    if(linkStatus[0] == 0){
        glDeleteProgram(programObjectId);
        if(LoggerConfig.ON){
            Log.w(TAG, "Linking of program failed.");
        }
        return 0;
    }

    return programObjectId;
}

public static boolean validateProgram(int programObjectId){
    glValidateProgram(programObjectId);

    final int[] validateStatus = new int[1];
    glGetProgramiv(programObjectId, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, validateStatus, 0);
    Log.v(TAG, "Results of validating program: " + "\nLog:" + glGetProgramInfoLog(programObjectId));
    return validateStatus[0] != 0;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Found some errors in the book, extra lines of code were in later chapters which made previous version work.

Comment: Yes, there were a lot of calls missing. `glShaderSource()`, `glCompileShader()`, etc.